# How to control the execution order of two pointcuts on the same package

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a situation where there is a generic pointcut and several other specific pointcuts.
All I want is generic should execute first and then only specific ones should.

Generic point cut is say,

```
  @Before("execution(public * com.java.*.data(..))")
```

Specific point cut number 1

```
  @Before("execution(public * com.java.science.*.data(..))")
```

Specific point cut number 2

```
  @Before("execution(public * com.java.history.*.data(..))")
```

Specific point cut number 3

```
  @Before("execution(public * com.java.geography.*.data(..))")
```

Genric point cut should execute first and then the specific ones. Can I have control on that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9052331/655756 maybe it would be usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the priority using an `@Order( value = ... )` on the `@Aspect`-annotated class:

```
@Aspect
@Order( value=0 )
public class MyFirstPointcut
{
    @Before("execution(public * com.java.*.data(..))")
    public void something(...) { ... }
}

@Aspect
@Order( value=1 )
public class MySecondPointcut
{
    @Before("execution(public * com.java.science.*.data(..))") 
    public void somethingElse(...) { ... }
}

...etc
```