# Does Sequence of method names in which they are specified in spring-aop-transaction.xml matter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-transactions, pointcut

I came across a spring-aop-transaction.xml file in my project.
There are two sections.

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor
        pointcut="execution
```

Here all the interfaces are declared.
And

```
<tx:advice id="TxAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
```

Here all the method names are specified.
I was wondering if the sequence in which the method names are mentioned make a difference or they have to be in exact same sequence as the declaration of the interfaces.

Thanks for the answers.

EDIT: 
How do I force close an open transaction.

EX:

```
<tx:method name="updateData" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"
    rollback-for="Exception"/>
```

This transaction is continued to be used by another method creating problems.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can mark order precedence for your aspects, means effectively your advises run in order http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering

@Order(2)

So when multiple point cuts matching a target, the advice get executed based on there order of precedence, means @Order(1) marked aspect(advice) get executed before @Order(2)

You can check an example done here
[Ordering aspects with Spring AOP && MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051728/ordering-aspects-with-spring-aop-mvc)